# How to get default css value after jquery function

Tags: jquery

Hi I have one questions 
For example :

```
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#left_panel, #main_footer").fadeToggle(200);
    $("#input_content").css({width:"100%"});
});
```

And I want after this function css get default property

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500500/reset-element-color-to-default-stylesheet-color-jquery-javascript

Comment: this looks like an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1053421/2115584

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default height value is `auto`, so you can set it back with:

```
$("#input_content").css({ width: 'auto' });
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to set the style to something useless. Then the browser won't interpret it and fall back to the rules you've defined in your CSS. The standard way would be setting it to an empty value:

```
$("#input_content").css("width","");
```

If you want to fully reset it to its default value defined by the browsers stylesheet, you may try to set the value to "initial":

```
$("#input_content").css("width","initial");
```

Or you set the default value yourself, which is "auto" ([See W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/width)).

Comment: I want when i again clicked `$("#menu")` selector get back default css value

Comment: Since .css() sets the styles inline, you may simply check if the element has the width attribute set or not.

`if($("#input_content")[0].style.width == "") { Set to 100% } else { reset to default (see my answer) }`

Comment: Please Write this example jsfiddle